# Undoing git push and pushing to another branch

Tags: git, branch, git-push

I have a branch that I've been working on (it was branched off master). Let's call it feature/ABC-1. It has not been merged back into master.
A colleague of mine branched of my feature/ABC-1 branch and did some work on his private branch. Let's call it private/ABC-extra.

He need me to fix something before he could continue working on his private branch, so I made the fixes and pushed my changes.

Unfortunately, I pushed my changes to my original branch (feature/ABC-1) instead of his private branch (private/ABC-extra).

I would like to somehow undo my push and then push the changes to his private branch.
But I want to do this in a way so that to him it appears as though I never made the bad push in the first place. I don't want him to have to fix any conflicts or have some strange history errors or anything like that.

Is this possible in git? If so, please tell me how.

Thank you!

P.S. I'm a git beginner. I just know some basic commands and concepts. So please be specific with commands and don't make assumptions. (otherwise I won't understand what you mean :D ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve it in two steps:

### First, let's update private/ABC-extra with feature/ABC-1 changes

You can do this by rebasing feature/ABC-1 into private/ABC-extra using these commands:

```
git checkout private/ABC-extra
git rebase feature/ABC-1
git push
```

Now you have all changes from *feature/ABC-1* rebased on *private/ABC-extra* and you pushed these changes to the remote.

### Second, let's remove the changes from remote feature/ABC-1

To do this, you will need first remove the changes from your local repository, then push force your branch to remote.

First, use git log to check how many commits do you want to remove by doing:

```
git checkout feature/ABC-1
git log
```

Then you can remove these commits by, imagine that you want to remove the last 3 commits:

```
git reset HEAD~3 --hard
git push --force
```

But attention, by using the --force flag you will force the remote branch to match exactly your local branch, losing any commits that you don't have your local.